# Eager loading relations for only a subset of records in a Laravel collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm working on a legacy Zend 1 project that's in the process of migrating to Laravel via the Strangler Pattern, and I'm using Eloquent for some of the database queries (though not all as they're still in the process of being migrated). Because Zend 1 can't work on any version of PHP higher than 7.1, it's stuck on the version of Eloquent from Laravel 5.8 until further notice.

I have one particular table containing navigation items, which has a nullable polymorphic relation for content items that uses a morph map to map the Eloquent models to the item types. One type, `static` doesn't have an Eloquent model assigned to it since it's just a container for other navigation items. Trying to eager load the relation on any items with the `static` type breaks it because it's not defined in the morph map, and setting it to null doesn't resolve the issue either.

Right now I load the items with a link type of `static` in a separate query and merge them with the query that gets the remaining navigation items, but this means there are two separate queries and that's not great for performance. Using a union doesn't resolve the issue because the eager load is a separate query from the one for the navigation items.

I know that it's possible to call `load()` on a collection after it's already been retrieved via a query in order to eager load a relation, and that it's also possible to constrain the eager load so that, for instance, a WHERE clause can be applied when loading the relation. What I'm trying to find is a means to ensure that the query only attempts to eager load the relation if the item type is not `static`. In other words, constraining not the query to get the relation, but excluding that record from the query so no attempt is made to retrieve the non-existent relation for that record.

Does anyone know if this is possible? One solution I can think of is to split off the items that aren't static in collections and apply `load()` there, but that's rather cumbersome and I was hoping there was a more elegant method.

Comment: Can you post [a code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you already have?

Comment: Not really. Basically, it's a polymorphic relationship, but if the type is `static`, that doesn't map to anything so it will break. So what I'm looking for is a way to call `with()` on a query, or `load()`, selectively, so it will only try to resolve ones where the type isn't `static`. So if the types were `foo`, `bar` and `static`, then using `with()` to eager load the relation would skip those items with the `static` type.

Comment: So the `navigation_items` table has an `item_id` and `item_type` field, and that represents a standard polymorphic relation. But if the `item_type` field is `static`, then there's no related item, and attempting to retrieve it will cause an error. So what I would like to be able to do is essentially constrain the eager load on the `navigation_items` table, not the related table, so that items with the `static` type are excluded from the eager load